# pandas/_libs/index.pyx KeyError: 'United States'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was searching for a row index with name 'United States' and it gives this error
when I try to assign to a new DataFrame. But I can print it? Any idea? Thanks

This gives KeyError `df = df.loc[country.strip(), :].to_frame()`

```
It's clearly in the index: United States
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/feiwhang/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 133, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 180, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer
KeyError: 'United States'
```

But, I can print it
`print(df.loc[country.strip(), :].to_frame())`

```
          United States
Confirmed          7783
Recovered             0
Death               118
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is data, 
i had the same problem, since my data consists of both integers and floats
array or matrix can have only one type of data
it can be fixed if you can change the data to be float or integer.

i update the original excel file to floats, and save as CSV (for some reason it won't update my file to floats) and run you program

hope it helps